# What javascript object prints as false, is truthy, and is type "object"?

Tags: javascript, birt

I'm trying to debug a BIRT report where I've retrieved a paramter from the reportContext like so: `var myParameter = reportContext.getParameterValue("myParameter");` BIRT has no debugger and BIRT javascript cannot access JSON.stringify, so I cannot examine what this variable is except by printing it. When I print it, it prints as "false". `typeof(myParameter)` is "object", `myParameter === null` evaluates to false, `myParameter === undefined` evaluates to false, `myParameter == "false"` evaluates to false, and myParameter is truthy (if I use it as the guard to an if statement, the if statement is executed). What the heck is this variable, and how can I determine what it is? Is there a way to stringify it without using JSON.stringify, which I cannot access in BIRT?

Comment: `{toString(){ return "false" }}` will do it. And many other objects.

Comment: What do you use to print, `console.log`? Try `console.dir` instead. If you can only print strings, write your own JSON stringifier.

Answer (score 7):

```
> new Boolean(false).toString()
'false'
> typeof new Boolean(false)
'object'
> !!new Boolean(false)
true
>
```

To check whether this is in fact your object, `new Boolean(false).constructor` returns (stringified) `[Function: Boolean]`.

Comment: Your answer was very close, and led me to figure out what it actually was: BIRT javascript can call Java code and use Java objects and classes - myParameter was BIRT's Javascript version of a Java Boolean object (not a Java boolean primitive, or a Javascript Boolean object, or a Javascript boolean primitive).

Comment: This answer shows once again why Javascript sucks. Part of my job is teaching Oracle Reports developers to work with BIRT, and one of the biggest obstacles is Javascript. I wish they had chosen a different language for logic inside a report...

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by SLaks was very close, and led me to figure out what it actually was: BIRT javascript can call Java code and use Java objects and classes - myParameter was BIRT's Javascript version of a Java Boolean object (not a Java boolean primitive, or a Javascript Boolean object, or a Javascript boolean primitive).

Answer (score 0):

Consider some custom object with a custom `toString()` function with the latter returning false.

```js
function MyType() {}

MyType.prototype.toString = function() { return "false"; };

var a = new MyType();

console.log( String( a ) );
console.log( typeof a );
console.log( Boolean( a ) );
```